# Android finishActivity always causing onActivityResult to get RESULT_CANCELED

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a main Activity A that can kick off sub-Activities B, C, or D.  I start them using startActivityForResult(newIntent, REQUEST_CODE);

The user can choose to navigate between B, C, and D once one is displayed.  Activity A controls that navigation.  When they choose swap between screens 'A' first calls finishActivity(REQUEST_CODE); on the one displayed and then call startActivityForResult(newIntent, REQUEST_CODE); for the next one.

In my onActivityResult I've got

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
   {
      // these logs are just for my debugging
      Log.w(this.toString(), "onActivityResult returned to by " + requestCode);
      Log.w(this.toString(), "result code = " + resultCode );

      // the Activity set this value if it was returning normally
      if (RESULT_OK == resultCode)
      {
         Log.i(this.toString(), "---- the sub-activity returned OK ----"); 
         // do some stuff    

      }// end if (RESULT_OK == resultCode)
      // Else we got here because the user hit the back button or something went
      // went wrong (RESULT_CANCELED).  Either way we do not want to display this
      // blank screen to the user.  Take them back to the device connection screen.
      else if (RESULT_CANCELED == resultCode)
      {    
         finish();
      }
    }
```

For some reason I'm getting back a zero or RESULT_CANCELED everytime even though in my sub-activities B,C,D I only set that result if the user chooses to hit the back button (I display an "are you sure" dialog and they choose to exit.  In B,C,D I have the following in onPause.  The userExiting is a flag I set from the Exit dialog.

```
protected void onPause()
   {
      Log.i(this.toString(), "onPause");

      // hack to try to setResult for an activity whose finishActivty was called
      if ( !this.exiting ) 
      {
         Log.i(this.toString(), "======== RESULT_OK ========"); 
         Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
         setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
         finish();
      }

      displayed = false;

      super.onPause();
   }
```

Any ideas?

Edit - to be clear the issue is that after calling finishActivty on the old Activity, since a result was never set, Activity A always thinks it should exit.  One weird side items.  This doesn't happen until the user navigates two times.  In other words B is displayed and they choose to go to C.  Works, but I can see in the log that onActivityResult hasn't been called.  User selects to go from C to D,  boom, I see two calls to onActivtyResult, 'A; exits and D is left displayed and the user is unable to nav away.

Update:  Since this has been getting a lot of views I thought I'd post this update.  The project evolved such that sometimes a single Activity is displays and sometimes a group are displayed as tabs.  When the user packs out of the tab in some cases data needed to be returned to the Activity that kicked off the tabs.  Before I added the code below RESULT_CANCELED would always be returned.  Also make sure that setResult is called before finish.

```
 if (getParent() == null)
 {
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
 }
 else
 {
    getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
 }
```

Comment: As an aside, are you sure you really need to show an are-you-sure dialog when moving back through activities?  I would find that really annoying.  Instead, you should just make it easy for the user to get back to where they were.

Comment: In my case my requirement is not to take them back to where they were but to exit if they press back, before we had the "are you sure" dialog users kept exiting by accident.  Once they leave A and are on to B,C, and D they never get back to A.

Comment: Oh, well maybe that is because that is not the expected behavior of the back button.  If I'm on one screen, I move to a new screen, then hit back I expect to go back to the previous screen. If you follow the paradigm that people are expecting, you'll have less problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite following everything you are doing here, but it doesn't sound like you are navigating between activities properly.  I would highly suggest reading through the [notepad example](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html) thoroughly so that you understand the android way of moving between Activities.

Here is what I understand regarding what you are trying to accomplish:  Activity A can navigate to B, C or D.  From B, C or D you can navigate to any of the others.

You are somehow trying to using Activity A as a controller, having it finish other Activities.  Don't do this.  Each Activity should be responsible for finishing itself at the proper point.

If you want to go from having A -> B on the stack to A -> C, then I would do this:

A starts B for result.  When user selects something in B asking to go to C you have a few choices.  You could have B start C not for result, then finish.  This would have the effect of B being removed from the stack when C exits.  Or, you could have B finish itself, passing back a note that C should be loaded in the results intent.  A could then load C for result.

I'm really not sure why you want this behavior though.  As an Android user, if I go from A -> B -> C, I expect hitting back to take me back to B.

As an aside, your "is exiting" hack doesn't make any sense.  By the time you get to onPause, the result has been set.  You cannot change it here.  You need to properly set the result when you are finishing, before onPause.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have not done the notepad example but will do so now.  You are right that I am using 'A' as a controller (probably incorrect, I'm in trouble if the system kills it).  I hear what you're saying about the Exit and Back button, but its a req I have to live with.  The tricky issue is that my app is coordinating with a server so C only indirectly navs to D.  Although it looks transparent to the user.  When the user selects to go from C to D, C sends request to do so to the server.  If the server responds OK, A actually gets that message and tells D to start.

Comment: Then A calls finshActivity on C.  For a reason I have yet to figure out I am not getting an immediate call back to onActivtyResult.  And when I do I'm always getting back 0.  I have even tried overriding onFinish and setting RESULT_OK.  But for some reason I'm not seeing onFinish get hit.  When I first posted this question after I navigated to 2 different screens suddenly I'd get both returning 0.  Then I was calling finishActivity and then startActivityForResult.  I've swapped that now and can nav B,C,D many times with no returns, I hit the back button, OK to exit, and bam they all come in

Comment: Can something hold onto an Activity to keep it from finishing?

Comment: I think you're suggestion about removing A as a controller is the ticket.  At one point I was passing ifo back to A, but I'm not currently, so why not kick off C from B, using start, fire and forget, and have B finish itself.  Thanks!