# Android Activity setResult not persistant?

Tags: android, android-activity

So I was trying a hack to put a quick bandaid on an issue I'm having that's described in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149764/android-finishactivity-always-causing-onactivityresult-to-get-result-canceled) I have posted.

I have a sub-activity that was kicked off by my main activity and it can also be stopped by the main activity calling finishActivity(requestCode) on it.  However the sub-activity is always returning 0 after the finishActivity call - even though I only set that result in the sub-activity if the user presses the back button.  I tried to cheat by calling setResult(RESULT_OK) in the sub-activity onResume method, but that seems like it makes no difference;

Also, for some reason it is taking a long time before the onActivityResults come in.  Is that normal?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observed the same bahaviour. In the main class that calls finishActivity() I had to remember ID of the Activity that I forced to close, so when it returns back in onActivityResult I can distinguish two cases:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case OUTSOURCED_INTENT:
            {
                if(mForcedClosingOfOutsourcedActivity)
                {
                    //Handles case of forced closing
                }
                else
                {
                    //Handles case of normal closing from Activity
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Definitely, it is not OK to wait so long time until Activity close.

Comment: Yes, I've got something odd going on I am checking the requestCode already and I know that its my sub-activity.  I've got two main issues, (1) I always get back RESULT_CANCELED even though I am calling setResult(RESULT_OK) in my onCreate and OnResume

Comment: (2) after calling finishActivity I don't get an immediate return, in fact it can be quite some time.  Its like something is preventing the sub-activity from being destroyed.

Comment: Ad (1): it is not fully without sense to get RESULT_CANCELED, because by calling finishActivity() it is canceled, not terminated as expected. The code I put is example how to overcome that behavior.

Comment: Thanks I ended up doing a similar approach.  In the sub-activities, if the user presses the back button and then selects yes to an "are you sure you want to exit?" popup, they set an addtional static flag in the parent activity.  Then when the onActivityResult hits in the parent activity it does a double check like yours.

Comment: else if (RESULT_CANCELED == resultCode)
      {
         if (isUserExiting())
         {         
            finish();
         }
      }